# Javascript return to top of code or restart it

Tags: javascript, return, restart

Hi I´m looking for a way to restart my code or return to the top of it to let it run again.
Is there a method or code I can look up and integrad it in my code??
As you can see I have an if statement with an input as a condition.
I would like to restart my code if we type reset in the console.

```js
//wiederholung von buchstaben message
//when entry is wrong or repeated --> list previous wrong letters
//Win message 
//difficulty

const constants = require('./constants');
// In node.js: install a prompt library by running: `npm install prompt-sync` in the current folder
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();

// Here you see an example how to get your
// constants from constants.js
/*for(let figure of constants.HANGMAN_PICS)
{
   console.log(figure);
}
*/
let answer = [];
let count = 0;
let usedLetters = [];

var word = constants.WORDS_TO_GUESS[Math.floor(Math.random()*constants.WORDS_TO_GUESS.length)];

for(let i=0; i < word.length; i++) {
   answer[i]="_";
}

console.log(answer.join(" "));

for(;answer!==word;) {

input = prompt (`Finde das Wort.`).toLocaleLowerCase();

if(word.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(input)) {
   for(let i=0; i < word.length; i++) {
   if (word[i].toLocaleLowerCase() === input) {
   console.clear();
   answer[i]=word[i];
   console.log("Good Job!");
   console.log(constants.HANGMAN_PICS[count]);
} 

}
}else if(!word.includes(input)){
   console.clear();
   console.log("Falsche Eingabe!");
   console.log("Hello");
   count++;
   console.log(constants.HANGMAN_PICS[count]); 
   if(usedLetters.includes(input)){
      console.log("Erneute Falscheingabe");
      console.log(usedLetters);
   }
 usedLetters.push(input);
}

if(input === "quit"){
   return;
}
else{

console.log(answer.join(" "));

}
}
// how to use the prompt - e.g.:
// const name = prompt('What is your name?');
```

Comment: Wrap the logic to run your game once is a function, like `function start() { ... }`. Whenever the game is at the end, call `start()` again and the logic should run again from the top.

Comment: We didn´t use functions just yet in our bootcamp, I tried to look how functions work but find it a bit difficult.

Comment: No problem, I'll try to explain some of it in an answer. For your code to work you'll need to add the content of your `constants.js` to your code snippet at the top.

Comment: You can use a loop. You've already used the for loop in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code that executes the logic of your game inside of a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Functions). Let's give this function the name `game` so we can reference and *call* it.

The code inside `game` won't run until we *invoke* the function. That means telling the function to start. To run the game, call the function with `game()`. The code inside the function will now run from top to bottom.

A function is able to call itself, meaning that you can restart the function, from **within** the function itself. This is called [recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#recursion).

In the snippet below game logic is defined inside of the `game` function. The function is then called which starts the logic. Inside the game we're asked to repeat the game. If `true` is the result from the `confirm` prompt, then `game` is called again, starting the logic from the top.

```js
function game() {
  const name = prompt('What is your name?');
  const repeat = confirm(`Hi ${name}, do you want to ask again?`);
  
  if (repeat === true) {
    game();
  }
}

game();
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same thing is :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Class Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        class Game{
            constructor(gameName){
                this.name = gameName;
            }
            init(){
                alert("Lets play at " + this.name);
                const userName = prompt('What is your name?');
                if (userName.length == 0){
                    alert("please fill the name field");
                    this.init();
                };
                const repeat = confirm(`Hi ${userName}, do you want to ask again?`);
                if (repeat == true) {
                    this.init();
                }
            }
        }
        let myGame = new Game("Simple Game");
        myGame.init();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everytime You want to restart the game, call :
`myGame.init();`

This code is longer but You will probably understand clearly how it works....

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Class Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outputDiv" style="font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', Verdana, 'sans-serif'; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
<script>
class SomeGame{
    constructor(name,targ){
        this.gameName = name; // The name of the game
        this.goal = targ; // The score You need to win
    }
        init(){
            this.score = 0;
            this.counter = 0;
            this.winMsg = false;
            document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = this.getResults();
            alert("We will play at " + this.gameName + " GET " + this.goal + " POINTS TO WIN!");
        }
        getScore(){
            return this.score;
        }
        getCounter(){
            return this.counter;
        }
        increaseScore(numb){
            this.score += numb;
        }
        increaseCounter(){
                this.counter += 1;
        }
        getResults(){
            let res = ("counter = " + this.getCounter() + ", score = " + this.getScore());
            return(res);
        }
        increaseValues(){
            if(this.score<this.goal){
                this.increaseScore(100);
                this.increaseCounter();
                document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = this.getResults();
            }
            if(this.score==this.goal && this.winMsg == false){
                alert("You win! You reached " + this.goal + " POINTS.");
                this.winMsg = true
            }
        }
    }
    let aGame = new SomeGame("Get 500", 500);
    aGame.init();
</script>   
<input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" value="Score++" onClick="aGame.increaseValues()">
<input type="button" name="button2" id="button2" value="Reset" onClick="aGame.init()">
</body>
</html>
```

Best regards.
Nicolas.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a goto statement. Javascript doesn't support it, and it is also considered bad practice in most languages that support it because it leads to spaghetti code.

It was widely used in languages like Fortran because there was no alternative to loops and such.

Like the other answers describe, you can simply wrap your code you want to repeat in a function and call it whenever you want to.